# "Specified visual is already a child of another visual or root of a CompositionTarget" C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a blank domino piece and I want to fill it with dots with this function:

```
private void Arrange(Grid grid, byte dots)
        {

            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
            };

            Border b = new Border
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5),
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(2.5)
            };

            //BoneView.Layout.Children.Add(b);
            Grid.SetColumn(b, 1);

            if (dots == 0)
                return;

            if (dots == 1)
            {
                grid.Children.Add(e);
                Grid.SetColumn(e, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(e, 1);
                return;
            }

            if (dots == 2)
            {
                List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
                {
                    ellipses.Add(e);
                    grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
                }


                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
                return;
            }

            if (dots == 3)
            {
                List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
                {
                    ellipses.Add(e);
                    grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
                }


                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 1);
                return;
            }

            if (dots == 4)
            {
                List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
                {
                    ellipses.Add(e);
                    grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
                }


                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);
                return;
            }

            if (dots == 5)
            {
                List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
                {
                    ellipses.Add(e);
                    grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
                }


                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[4], 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[4], 1);
                return;
            }

            if (dots == 6)
            {
                List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
                {
                    ellipses.Add(e);
                    grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
                }

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[4], 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[4], 0);

                Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[5], 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ellipses[5], 2);
                return;
            }
```

At `grid.Children.Add(e)` it throws "Specified visual is already a child of another visual or root of a CompositionTarget" exception.

From what I understand this happens because Ellipse `e` is already added to the grid.

How do I fix this?

Here is the domino design:

```
<Border Background="AntiqueWhite"
            CornerRadius="7"
            >

        <Grid Name="Layout">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Left">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Right">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Border>
```

Comment: It's because you instantiate the `Ellipse` at the top of your function, this code `Ellipse e = new Ellipse...`, and then when a domino has multiple dots you add the same `e` for each dot. You need to instantiate the `Ellipse` _each_ time you want to add a dot. The simple solution would be to instantiate the `Ellipse` in the `for...each` loops where you are adding the dots. Then each loop iteration you are creating a new dot and thus will not be adding the same dot `Ellipse` multiple times but a new dot for each on added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you instantiate the `Ellipse` at the top of your function, this code `Ellipse e = new Ellipse`..., and then when a domino has multiple dots you add the same instantiated `e` for each dot you are adding. You need to instantiate the `Ellipse` each time you want to add a dot.

The simple solution would be to instantiate the `Ellipse` in the `for...each` loops where you are adding the dots, as I've done in the below.

```
private void Arrange(Grid grid, byte dots)
{
    // let's create a single brush for all the black dots
    // so we don't have to create a brush for each dot
    var blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    Border b = new Border
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5),
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(2.5)
    };

    //BoneView.Layout.Children.Add(b);
    Grid.SetColumn(b, 1);

    if (dots == 0)
        return;

    if (dots == 1)
    {
        // create ellipse to add
        Ellipse e = new Ellipse
        {
            Fill = blackBrush 
        };
        grid.Children.Add(e);
        Grid.SetColumn(e, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(e, 1);
        return;
    }

    if (dots == 2)
    {
        List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
        {
            // create each ellipse to add
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = blackBrush 
            };
            ellipses.Add(e);
            grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
        return;
    }

    if (dots == 3)
    {
        List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
        {
            // create each ellipse to add
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = blackBrush 
            };
            ellipses.Add(e);
            grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 1);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 1);
        return;
    }

    if (dots == 4)
    {
        List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
        {
            // create each ellipse to add
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = blackBrush 
            };
            ellipses.Add(e);
            grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);
        return;
    }

    if (dots == 5)
    {
        List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
        {
            // create each ellipse to add
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = blackBrush 
            };
            ellipses.Add(e);
            grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[4], 1);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[4], 1);
        return;
    }

    if (dots == 6)
    {
        List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++)
        {
            // create each ellipse to add
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = blackBrush 
            };
            ellipses.Add(e);
            grid.Children.Add(ellipses[i]);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[1], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[2], 2);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[2], 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[3], 0);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[3], 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[4], 1);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[4], 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(ellipses[5], 1);
        Grid.SetRow(ellipses[5], 2);
        return;
    }
}
```